# Autosave in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Visual Studio for mac 2017 for my scripts in Unity, and it's very bad that every single time that I want to run my Project on Unity I have to Save all my files in Visual Studio. is there anyway that I can make my VS save files on the fly?

Comment: There are third party Tools in the [Market](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VS&category=Tools&vsVersion=&subCategory=All&sortBy=Downloads) such as [AutoSave](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AutoSaveAndCompile.Autosave). I don't think Visual Studio has anything built in for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly this is currently not possible in VS for Mac (Version 8.0.9).
They added it in the Pro version so hopefully it will move over at some point :)

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/497369/autosave-feature-for-vs2019-pro-mac-preview.html

Answer (score -6):

By default, VS Code requires an explicit action to save your changes to disk, Ctrl+S.

However, it's easy to turn on Auto Save, which will save your changes after a configured delay or when focus leaves the editor. With this option turned on, there is no need to explicitly save the file. The easiest way to turn on Auto Save is with the **File > Auto Save** toggle which turns on and off save after a delay.

For more control over Auto Save, open User or Workspace settings and find the associated settings:

**files.autoSave: Can have the values:**

**off** - to disable auto save.

**afterDelay** - to save files after a configured delay (default 1000 ms).

**onFocusChange** - to save files when focus moves out of the editor of the dirty file.
**onWindowChange** - to save files when the focus moves out of the VS Code window.

**files.autoSaveDelay**: Configures the delay in milliseconds when files.autoSave is configured to afterDelay. The default is 1000 ms.

Comment: the question is asking about Visual Studio for Mac, not VS Code.

Comment: The question is related to Visual Studio for Mac and not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio for Mac not VS Code, VS for Mac does not have such menus.

Comment: Hey, did you hear that this question is about Visual Studio for Mac and not VS Code? Just want to make sure, it's been a few months since someone said it

Comment: Hey there, just making sure you caught that. He was talking about Visual Studio for Mac, not VS Code.